# Why wget can't work when I perform it in SSH?

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I have the following problem.

I am using my RaspBerry (with RaspBian installed) by **SSH**.

My problem is that I can't use **wget** command because it fails.

For example if I try to execute the following command:

```
sudo wget http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
```

I obtain this error message:

```
--2014-05-29 19:39:11--  http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
Resolving dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address `dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com'
pi@raspberrypi ~/driverWireless $ sudo wget http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg
```

The strange thing is that I can ping it:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/driverWireless $ ping dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com
PING dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (192.0.80.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (192.0.80.175): icmp_req=1 ttl=41 time=164 ms
64 bytes from dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com (192.0.80.175): icmp_req=2 ttl=41 time=167 ms
```

Why? What can I do to solve this issue?

(on my Ubuntu Linux system I have no problem to perform wget command)

Comment: Have you tried the wget command without using sudo?  Not sure why sudo would change ability to resolve DNS requests.  Are you using any proxy settings?  sudo would remove those environment variables holding the proxy settings.  Hmmm

Comment: Is this a private IP? I looks like your requesting data from an internal network. You could be missing a local DNS server in `hosts`. Why ping works and not wget... it could just be a DNS server replying to the ICMP request, instead of the intended host. Try replace the host with IP instead and request path the same. - but its likely to fail since it looks like a multi tenant address. try traceroute . `sudo apt-get install traceroute` then `traceroute [ip/web-site url]` see what is going on.

Comment: It's not a great idea to run `wget` as root. Imagine someone hacks the target website and puts a malicious file there that targets a bug in wget. Now they have a root shell on your system.

Comment: Hello @AndreNObili - Did you try any of these?

Comment: I discovered that if I force wget to use ipv4 by wget -4 it work fine. But I can't understand why have this issue

Comment: There are other commands you can use - e.g. `curl http://dietrofuoritempo.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/bla-bla.jpg > bla-bla.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the answers to [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/76421/wget-cant-resolve-host), check the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, my Pi has this entry for `hosts:`

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

According to [this document](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html), `mdns4` is Multicast DNS and `[NOTFOUND=return]` means any response of Not Found to the Multicast DNS request will be returned as authoritative prior to attempting a Unicast DNS request.

The article goes on to say that you can reverse the order of dns and mdns4_minimal to prefer legacy Unicast DNS over Multicast DNS as shown in the updated `/etc/nsswitch.conf` entry below:

```
hosts:          files dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4_minimal mdns4
```